# Iterate through an array, one at the time for a quiz

Tags: javascript, function, loops

**Trying to make a quiz** where the user will get one question displayed at the time. Then when they answer and hit "next question" the next question is displayed.

I've tried to make a function where the onclick will iterate to the next indexValue. I tried to use the if(){}else function to make each indexValue equal to 0, 1, 2, 3 and so on. The plan was to "if(indexValue === 0)" then it would stop, until you hit the "next question" button. I did not get that to work. Does anyone know how I could make the for loop stop at each question, then when the user hit "next question" button, the for loop goes to the next question?

Now when you hit, "next question" button, the for loop just runs through the questions and answers and stops at the last one.

code is under:

*HTML CODE:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" 
   rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

   <div id="quizField">

    <div id="question"></div>

    <button type="button" id="answerOne"></button>

    <button type="button" id="answerTwo"></button>

    <button type="button" id="answerThree"></button>

    <br>

    <button type="button" onclick="buttonFunction()">Next 
     question</button>

 </div>    
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*JS CODE:*

```
var questionArr = [
{
question: "How many states in USA?",
answerOne: "50",
answerTwo: "48",
answerThree: "52"
},
{
question: "Where is Norway?",
answerOne: "America",
answerTwo: "Europ",
answerThree: "Asia"
}
];

function buttonFunction(){
    for(var i = 0; i < questionArr.length; i += 1){

    function getQuestion(){
        var questionInner = document.getElementById("question");
        return questionInner.innerHTML = questionArr[i].question;
    }
    getQuestion();

    function getAnswerOne(){
        var answerOneInner = document.getElementById("answerOne");
        return answerOneInner.innerHTML = questionArr[i].answerOne;
    }
    getAnswerOne();


    function getAnswerTwo(){
        var answerTwoInner = document.getElementById("answerTwo");
        return answerTwoInner.innerHTML = questionArr[i].answerTwo;
    }
    getAnswerTwo();

    function getAnswerThree(){
        var answerThreeInner = document.getElementById("answerThree");
        return answerThreeInner.innerHTML = questionArr[i].answerThree;
    }
    getAnswerThree();
  }
}
```

*CSS CODE:*

```
body{
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
font-family: serif;
font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
}

#quizField{
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#question{
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 900;
margin: 20px;
}

#answerOne{
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
}

#answerTwo{
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
}

#answerThree{
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 500;
}

button{
padding: 8px 15px;
color: white;
background-color: forestgreen;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 0px;
margin: 10px;
}

button:hover{
   background-color: limegreen;
}
```

Comment: I would use a global scope variable, and increment it each time the user calls the next answer button, not a loop, the loop is going to be executed super fast

Comment: okey, so a function that uses a loop to increment a variable in the global scope each time i hit the next question button, or is there another way to increment a variabel without a loop? Thanks for the help

Comment: You definitely do not want to have a loop here, as @Ferus7 said, the loop will execute very quickly.  You want to have a variable somewhere, a global value in your javascript, that you can increment to access the next question when it is time to do that.  There are other ways that you can make this code more efficient - have a parameterized function to get your answers instead of separate functions, or store the answers in an array and have a loop to output the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose you can benefit from [Iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). Just call `next()` on every click.

Quick demo:

```js
const array = ['question one', 'question two', 'question three'];

const it = array[Symbol.iterator]();

const el = document.getElementById('question');

document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
  let next = it.next(); // get the next element
  (next.done) ? 
   [el.innerText, this.innerText, this.disabled] = ['Complete!', 'Done', true]
   : el.innerText = next.value;
}
```

```html
<div id="question">Ready?</div>

<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: cool, I understand all of the code, except for this line
"const it = array[Symbol.iterator]();" can you explain it a little more in depth to me? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @AndersLund `Symbol.iterator` is a built-in property for iterable objects, for example arrays. It acts behind the scenes when you iterate using for...of loop. In ES6 Symbols were exposed in general, and built-in symbols in particular. You can read about array.iterator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator . Inportant to know: each iteration returns an object { value: ..., done: true/false}. When array is finished, done = true.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82sz7j6q/2/) to help you moving.

At the beginning declare global variable where you store current question's index. Optionally, you could store it as a `data` attribute on the DOM element.

```
window.nextQuestionIndex = 0;
```

On button click then pass this index to a function which fetches element based on this index. Then increment index by one for a next question. You won't need to use for loop then.

```
nextQuestion(window.nextQuestionIndex);
window.nextQuestionIndex++;
```

Comment: thanks :) quick question, what does the window in window.nextQuestionIndex do? :)

Comment: It's object, for a current webpage. It could be only `var nextQuestionIndex = 0;` in this example, this variable would be added to a `window` object. But using `window` it's more readable, especially when you have much more ccode and more scopes